# Shared Ownership of existing ressource programming pattern

Tags: c++, smart-pointers, lifetime, ownership, expression-templates

I know that questions on shared ownership on existing ressources have been asked quite a few times before, but somehow I failed to find an answer to my specific problem. Please correct me if I am wrong.

I am working an an expression template library. This is a bit of a toy library, and one thing that I want to explore is the pros and cons of encoding an algorithm using C++ types via expression templates. This could be used e.g. for lazy evaluation and also algorithmic differentiation. For this to work, a user of the library should be able to modify existing chunks of code, so that it uses the expression templates of my library under the hood via operator overloading.

Now I am unsure how to handle ownership of subexpressions. As an example, consider the following fuction:

```cpp
auto Foo() (
    auto alpha = [...]; // some calculation, result is an expression, e.g. Div<Sub<Value,Value>,Sub<Value,Value>>
    return (1-alpha)*something + alpha*something_else;
)
```

This function creates a new expression of type

```
Add<Mult<Sub<Value,TYPE_OF_ALPHA>,TYPE_OF_SOMETHING>, Mult<TYPE_OF_ALPHA, TYPE_OF_SOMETHING_ELSE>>
```

It seems clear, that the expressions representing `1-alpha` and `alpha*something_else` should take **shared ownership** of `alpha`, since `alpha` will go out of scope as we exit `Foo`. This tells me, I should use `shared_ptr` members to subexpressions in the expressions. - Or is this already a misconception?

### My question

How would I write the constructors of my binary operation expressions `Sub` and `Mult`, such that expressions truely take up shared ownership of the objects/subexpressions/operands passed into the constructor - in such a way, that the changes a user has to make to the function `Foo` stays minimal?

- I don't want to move the object into `1-alpha`, since this invalidates `alpha` before I call the constructor of `alpha*something_else`.
- If I use `make_shared`, both expressions store `shared_ptr`s to *copies* of `alpha`, which is not really shared onwership. Evaluating the resulting expression would mean that each copy of alpha gets evaluated, yielding redundant calculations.
- I could create a `shared_ptr` to `alpha` in the function body `Foo`, and pass this pointer by value to the constructors of `1-alpha` and `alpha*something_else`. But this would be a burden on the user of the library. Preferably, the implementation details get nicely hidden behind operator overloads: Ideally, a user would need only minimal changes to their existing `Foo` function to use it with the expression template library. *Am I asking for too much, here?*

---

### Edit 1:

Here is an example, where I use the second option, of creating copies in the constructors (I think...): https://godbolt.org/z/qn4h3q

---

### Edit 2:

I found a solution that works, but I am reluctant to answer my own question because I am not 100% satisfied with my solution.

If we want to take up shared ownership of a ressource that is a custom class, that we can modify *(which it is in my case)*, we can equip the class with a `shared_ptr` to a copy of itself. The `shared_ptr` is `nullptr` as long as nobody takes up ownership of the object.

```cpp
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>

class Expression
{
public:
    Expression(std::string const& n)
     : name(n) 
     {}
    ~Expression(){
        std::cout<<"Destroy "<<name<<std::endl;
    }

    std::shared_ptr<Expression> shared_copy()
    {
        return shared_ptr? shared_ptr : shared_ptr = std::make_shared<Expression>(*this);
    }

    std::string name;
    std::shared_ptr<Expression> subexpression;
private:
    std::shared_ptr<Expression> shared_ptr = nullptr;
};


int main()
{
    // both a and b shall share ownership of the temporary c
    Expression a("a");
    Expression b("b");

    {
        Expression c("c");
        a.subexpression = c.shared_copy();
        b.subexpression = c.shared_copy();

        // rename copy of c now shared between a and b
        a.subexpression->name = "c shared copy";
    }
    
    std::cout<<"a.subexpression->name = "<<a.subexpression->name<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<"b.subexpression->name = "<<b.subexpression->name<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<"b.subexpression.use_count() = "<<b.subexpression.use_count()<<std::endl;
}
```

Output:

```
Destroy c
a.subexpression->name = c shared copy
b.subexpression->name = c shared copy
b.subexpression.use_count() = 2
Destroy b
Destroy a
Destroy c shared copy
```

Live Code example: https://godbolt.org/z/xP45q6.

Here is an adaptation of the code example given in **Edit 1** using actual expression templates: https://godbolt.org/z/86YGfe.

The reason why I am not happy with this is because I am worried I just really killed any performance gain that I could hope to get from ETs. First of all, I have to carry around `shared_ptr`s to operands, which is bad enough as it is and second of all, an expression has to carry around an additional `shared_ptr` just for the freak case, that it will be used in a temporary/scoped context. ETs are meant to be light-weight.

Comment: yeah, so you rule out the points, which leaved the copy-constructor. Just pass by value. (Why didn't you consider that?)

Comment: Some way to avoid ownership issue is to split expression template from computation, I mean something like in [CppCon 2015: Joel Falcou PART 3 “Expression Templates: Past, Present, Future”](https://youtu.be/A9trwnv6k-w?t=873)

Comment: @Jarod42, thanks for the link! I don't really understand what you mean by "split expression template from computation", but maybe I will once I watched the video. From the description it sounds like exactly what I need to be watching right now :)

Comment: Basically, terminal variables are not stored in AST, but just a placeholder. So no issues of life time of terminal variables as there are not present.

Comment: @Jarod42 Thanks for introducing me to `boost::proto`/`boost::yap`, I think I will consider using yap for my project. But I still don't see how I can solve my problem: Yap doesn't handle this correctly _(by default)_ either: https://godbolt.org/z/85PMT8. The [suggestion in the yap manual](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_74_0/doc/html/boost_yap/manual.html#boost_yap.manual.how_expression_operands_are_treated) tells me I should use `std::move` in such cases, but I am really reluctant to `std::move` from `alpha` twice, as mentioned in my question. How would I implement this using placeholders?

Comment: With placeholder, you return an "(ast) function", You really compose functions, then at the end apply to variable x. Ast expression expression is more complicated as it has to handle ownership of values.

Answer (score 0):

If you pass the `shared_ptr` bij value, you give the receiver shared ownership of the object. Simple example

```cpp
#include <memory>

struct Sub{
    std::shared_ptr<int> a,b;
};

#include <cstdio>

int main() {
    auto s = Sub{};
    {
        auto v = std::make_shared<int>(5);
        s = Sub{v,v};
    }
    printf("reference count %ld", s.a.use_count());
}
```

returns: `reference count 2`

Comment: This would be what I meant with _"I could contrieve of some other way of creating a shared_ptr in Foo, and pass that to the constructors of 1-alpha and alpha*something_else. But this would be a burden on the user of the library. Preferably, the implementation details get nicely hidden behind operator overloads."_. But then, maybe there is no way to achieve what I am trying to do and your solution might be the best compromise...

Comment: @joergbrech then you should give a better example of what you are trying to achieve and how you solve it now. "some other way" is kind of broad... Please be as specific as you can.

Comment: You are right. I will edit this bullet point of the question

Comment: I added a code example, see here: https://godbolt.org/z/qn4h3q

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that for my usecase I can avoid shared ownership alltogether. Most expression template libraries provide an `EVALUTION_EXPRESSION`, which represents the evaluation of a function, given some arguments that may be expressions. When evaluating an `EVALUATION_EXPRESSION` the arguments get evaluated first and their results are passed into the function.

Using this, I can define a `linear_combine` function and wrap it in an `EVALUATION_EXPRESSION`, which shall be the sole owner of `alpha`:

```cpp
template <typename Scalar, typename Vector>
Vector linear_combine(Scalar alpha, Vector const& x, Vector const& y){
   return (1.-alpha)*x + alpha*y;
}

auto Foo() (
    auto alpha = [...]; // some calculation, result is an expression, e.g. Div<Sub<Value,Value>,Sub<Value,Value>>
    return EVALUTION_EXPRESSION(linear_combine)(std::move(alpha), something, something_else);
)
```

Here is a [Live Code Example](https://godbolt.org/z/ancf4c) using the expression template library [boost::yap](https://github.com/boostorg/yap).